# Электронная подпись для индентефикации та шифрования текстовых документов

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Пишу приложения которое хранит текстовые файлы. Пытаюсь разобраться как использовать электронную цифровую подпись. Суть моей задачи: пользователь "A" заливает свой текстовый документ, во время чего текстовый документ шифруется с помощью ключа пользователя "A". Например, другой пользователь "B" чтобы открыть файл должен будет ввести данные нужного ключа, чтобы расшифровать содержимое. Таким образом у каждого пользователя есть ключ("подпись") которым он шифрует и тем самым при доступе к файлу он идентифицирует себя вводя нужный ключ. Я, честно говоря, полный ноль в этой теме. Пробовал с помощью RSACryptoServiceProvider.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TXTSystem_context context = new TXTSystem_context();

        List<Users> users = context.Users.ToList();



        string dataString = File.ReadAllText(@"F:\Music List.txt");
        byte[] rawstring = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(dataString);
        RSACryptoServiceProvider crypto_provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        RSAParameters private_key = crypto_provider.ExportParameters(true);

        RSAParameters key = new RSAParameters();
        key.Modulus = private_key.Modulus;
        key.Exponent = private_key.Exponent;
        key.D = private_key.D;
        key.DP = private_key.DP;
        key.DQ = private_key.DQ;
        key.InverseQ = private_key.InverseQ;
        key.P = private_key.P;
        key.Q = private_key.Q;

        byte[] encrypted = Encrypt(rawstring, private_key);
        string EncryptedString = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);

        byte[] todecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(EncryptedString);
        byte[] decrypted = Decrypt(todecrypt, private_key);
        string decryptedstring = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decrypted);
        Console.WriteLine(decryptedstring);

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, RSAParameters parameters)
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        provider.ImportParameters(parameters);
        return provider.Encrypt(data, false);
    }


    public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data, RSAParameters parameters)
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        provider.ImportParameters(parameters);
        return provider.Decrypt(data, false);
    }
```

Так как я собираюсь хранить ключ в MS SQL Server базе, то буду хранить все эти параметры для ключа(Moduls,Exponent,D,DP,DQ,InverseQ,P,Q).
Основная проблема в том, что таким методом я не могу шифровать большие текстовые файлы(лишь мелкие предложения). Из этого возникает вопрос, RSA не подходит для реализации электронной подписи для больших текстовых файлов? Или я делаю все не правильно, и вообще не понимаю суть электронной подписи и как она должна работать(Скорей всего). Я честно говоря полный ноль в этом, помогите разобраться, незнаю честно говоря даж как правильно загуглить.

Comment: Шифрование и цифровые подписи - чуть-чуть разные вещи для разных целей...

Comment: Да и `RSA` вроде ассиметричный алгоритм шифрования, если я что-то не путаю.

Comment: Я вроде и понимаю, а вроде и нет. Шифрование защищает данные, цифровая подпись определяет владельца данных.  Вот тут я и не догоняю, что лучше для моей задачи подойдет. Но цифровая подпись разве не подразумевает некое шифрование подписанных данных?

Comment: Смогу ли я подписывать большие текстовые файлы?

Comment: Шифрование - это кодирование информации для **последующей его расшифровки**. Расшифровать же подпись **нельзя** - имея исходник его можно верифицировать (т.е вам требуется иметь и исходник, и подпись, чтобы верифицировать)

Comment: я не понял, честно говоря, что представляет собой сама подпись? Это некоторый байтовый масив который характеризует текстовый документ? Или это измененный текст, который расшифровать нельзя,  но можно верифицировать?

Comment: Вот пример: вы сделали какой-то документ и хотите отдать его своем бизнес партнеру. Вы отправляете этот документ ему по почте. Но как вы можете быть уверены, что хулиган не изменит что-то в нем? Никак! Поэтому приходит на помощь ЭЦП! Вы сделали документ, подписали его **закрытым ключом**, отправили товарищу исходник документа и **открытый (публичный) ключ**, а он уже у себя проверит данный документ и его подпись. Если документ был изменен в процессе передачи - то документ и подпись не совпадут.

Comment: Понял, есть над чем подумать. Скорей всего не буду делать цифровую подпись, а просто зашифрую текстовые документы. Цифровая подпись я так понял нужно, только если идет передача данных между пользователями(у меня обычное хранение)

Answer (score 0):

Стоит разделять понятия **шифрования** и **цифровой подписи**.

Согласно [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) это:

> Шифрова́ние — **обратимое преобразование информации** в целях скрытия от
>   неавторизованных лиц...

Т.е зашифровав что-то можно будет это что-то расшифровать.

Согласно той же [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) ЭЦП - это:

> Электро́нная цифровая по́дпись (ЭЦП) — реквизит электронного
>   документа, полученный в результате **криптографического преобразования**
>   информации с использованием **закрытого ключа** подписи и позволяющий
>   **проверить отсутствие искажения информации** в электронном документе с
>   момента формирования подписи (целостность)...

Т.е ЭЦП служит для проверки **целостности** документа в основном. К слову, криптосистема обязана быть ассиметричной.

Теперь перейдем к алгоритмам шифрования. Существует два типа:

- **Симметричные** - один и тот же ключ для шифрования-расшифрования;
- **Ассиметричные** - публичный ключ для шифрования, приватный для расшифровки. Или если говорим о ЭЦП - публичный для верификации, приватный для подписи документа.

Если вдаваться в подробности, то вам также стоит прочитать статьи про криптографическую стойкость алгоритмов, их слабости, про длину ключей шифрования и тд.

---

Для примера оставлю тут реализацию шифрования с помощью симметричной криптосистемы AES64 с 128-битным ключом.

[Потестить пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y5JUMw)!

```
public class Aes64Cryptor
{
    private const int InitializationVectorSize = 16;
    private const int BufferSize = 4 * 1024;

    private readonly byte[] _key;


    public Aes64Cryptor(byte[] key)
    {
        _key = PrepareKey(key);
    }


    public byte[] EncryptBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        using (var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider { Key = _key })
        {
            aes.GenerateIV();
            using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor())
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                memoryStream.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length);
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cryptoStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

                    return memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public byte[] DecryptBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var iv = bytes.Take(InitializationVectorSize).ToArray();
        var encryptedContent = bytes.Skip(InitializationVectorSize).ToArray();
        using (var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider { Key = _key, IV = iv })
        using (var decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor())
        using (var encryptedStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedContent))
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
            int count;
            while ((count = cryptoStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            }

            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }


    // тут мы подгоняем размер массива байт ключа под InitializationVectorSize :)
    private static byte[] PrepareKey(byte[] key)
    {
        var keyList = key.ToList();
        while (keyList.Count < InitializationVectorSize)
        {
            keyList.AddRange(keyList);
        }
        return keyList.Take(InitializationVectorSize).ToArray();
    }
}
```